suddenly meet some problem with ts compiler and EventEmitter
just found this from my friend (thx Jeremy also)
https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/10358
i now downgrade my ts version to 5.4
kinda solved the issue, at least compilation successes.
---edit---
I'm writing my discord bot with typescript and one day recently it just don't get EventEmitter type define for some part of my code. the discord.js client is fine with it. but others like the mongoose connection, djs collector just can't pass the compilation. i can't figure out where the problem comes from. 
Property 'on' does not exist on type 'Connection'. Did you mean to access the static member 'Connection.on' instead?

22     connection.on(event, callback);
                  ~~

error TS2339: Property 'emit' does not exist on type 'InteractionCollector<ButtonInteraction<CacheType>>'.

38                     end(interaction, orderlist, () => collector.emit('end'));
                                                                   ~~~~

Property 'emit' does not exist on type 'InteractionCollector<StringSelectMenuInteraction<CacheType> | UserSelectMenuInteraction<CacheType> | RoleSelectMenuInteraction<CacheType> | MentionableSelectMenuInteraction<...> | ChannelSelectMenuInteraction<...> | ButtonInteraction<...>>'.

153                             collector.emit('end');
                                          ~~~~

I've updated the dependencies
install @types/node seperately
reinstall node_modules
change to another pc (I'm using macbook)
npm list
├── @discordjs/builders@1.8.2
├── @discordjs/voice@0.16.1
├── @types/node@20.14.10
├── chalk@4.1.2
├── discord.js@14.15.3
├── ffmpeg-static@5.2.0
├── get-root-path@2.0.2
├── libsodium-wrappers@0.7.13
├── mongoose@8.4.5
└── typescript@5.5.3 (before I updated this was 5.3.3)

node version:
v20.11.0
btw this is my first post, tell me if need more information.

I ran into the same issue. It sounds like there is an EventEmitter naming conflict between the discord.js library and @types/node. This is being discussed in this GitHub issue in the discord.js project.
As a temporary workaround, I pinned my TypeScript devDependency to 5.4.x ("~5.4.0"). I'm running VS Code from a WSL2 instance, and also had to configure VS Code to use the project version and not its built-in version. If that is your case, press Ctrl-Shift-P while editing a .ts file, find "Select TypeScript version..." and click "Use Workspace Version", as the VS Code version is currently 5.5.2.
I hope this helps for now!

I'll try select typescript version. thx

nice finally no error in vsc
